# How to fix FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (337867) exceeds the configured maximum (200)

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, tags

How to handle custom inteceptors execptions in Struts 2?

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: 
the request was rejected because its size (337867) exceeds the configured 
maximum (200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<global-exception-mappings>
  <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.NullPointerException" result="npe"/>
</global-exception-mappings>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set this constant to increase a request limit

```
<constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
```

> Please remember that the struts.multipart.maxSize is the size limit of the whole request, which means when you uploading multiple files, the sum of their size must be below the struts.multipart.maxSize!